# how to Design a vista like button using CSS

Tags: asp.net, css

can any one tell me the way to design vista like buttons using CSS  for the application in  ASP.NET.

For the Buttons like Save,delete,Cancel etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this : http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/css_square_buttons/

Comment: Those are very pretty, but I would strongly recommend the OP use an `input` or a `button` for accessibility and built-in behavior. I'm sure you could get the nice-looking stuff from that link to work with a `button` element, with some tweaking.